# Rolling file log in Console application using nlog

Tags: .net, logging, nlog

NLog's file target is [pretty configurable](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/File_target#One_log_file_per_day), but it doesn't seem to support what I am trying to achieve.

My console application writes messages to a log file, but I want it to do two things:

- Start a new log file on each run.  So each time the application is started, a new log file should be created.
- Previous log files should not be overwritten or deleted, i want to keep the `x` latest runs as well.

The archive* properties seem to be pretty close, but they do the rolling on a *time* basis, not an *execution* basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is somewhat easy. Set the filename to `"log-${cached:${date:format=yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss}}.log"` or something similar. This will set up the file with a down-to-the-second name, which will be cached on each application execution.

As far as your second request, that's a bit more difficult. You might try setting `archiveEvery: "None"` and `maxArchiveFiles: x`, but I'm not sure if that would produce the desired behaviour or just never archive anything at all.

Comment: I'd suggest also adding a guid to prevent simultaneous invocations from trying to write to the same file.

Comment: The archiving does not work, but the cached makes sure that the log sticks for the entire run and that a new one is created on each go. Therefore, awarding the bounty.

Comment: Yeah, I've not been able to replicate the kind of behaviour you want for archival. I think it's a feature worth requesting from the nlog developers; it seems like one that would be common. I know for one application I've worked on, the per-execution log was definitely the way to go, and archival based on a simple count would have been beneficial. It's something they should consider adding.